# Calling a SOAP web service in a C# client

Tags: c#, wcf, web-services, c#-4.0, soap

I have a SOAP web service  to be called and used in my C# app. This web service is **not** `asmx` or `svc` .

I know the WSDL link of this service.

Also I know the **SOAP HEADER** should be of this format:

```
<soapenv:Header>
  <wsse:Security soap:mustUnderstand="1" 
         xmlns:wsse="http://abc.org/wss/20XX/CC/qwerty.xsd" 
   xmlns="http://abc.org/wss/20XX/XX/oasis-20XXXX-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd" 
   xmlns:env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:soap="soap">
    <wsse:UsernameToken>
      <wsse:Username>********</wsse:Username>
      <wsse:Password>********</wsse:Password>
    </wsse:UsernameToken>
  </wsse:Security>
</soapenv:Header>
```

I know the specific `Username` and `Password`  values that need to be passed.

Considering all this, this is what I have done so far:

1. Added the WSDL as a Service Reference to my project.
2. I am able to access all the service functionality while coding and create the request objects.

But my call fails with a there is no listener at the endpoint error with timeout.

My question:

**1.** I am not creating a SOAP Header specifically. How should I do this?

Answer (score 0):

You may want to enable the WCF tracing functionality, which provides a built-in method to monitor communication to/from WCF services. For test and debugging environments, configure informational or verbose activity tracing and enable message logging. The combination of activity tracing and message logging should prove beneficial when initially deploying and testing new services or adding new operations and/or communication bindings to existing services.

The following links provide a good overview:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733025.aspx
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa702726.aspx

Regards,